# button control on form to manipulate Web Browser control web page

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I was hoping that someone could answer me a question, I don't need any code but more a helpful direction to start researching.

Here is my situation

I have a windows Form program that if I placed a button control on and a web browser control on. The web browser will have a page in it that is mostly javascript driven..now lets say thru javascipt on the web page I created a checkbox control on the webpage.  Is there any way I could get my button control on my windows form to check that box?  Im sorry if I am not explaining myself right still getting used to the lingo.

Thanks in advance guys
This site is a wealth of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have WebBrowser control. Handle it's DocumentCompleted event and start you work here. Now you can work with WebBrowser.Document, WebBrowser.Document.Body to interact with your page.

For example, you can use `wb.Document.InvokeScript` with some parameters to handle the updates.

Or you can go directly

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("your_Element_ID").SetAttribute("checked", "checked")
```